# How do I go to the Wordpress Dashboard?

Tags: wordpress

I installed wordpress in my wamp local server and created a site using a theme. Up to this time I was using the dashboard link that is available in one of the page in the theme itself to log in to wordpress and use the dashboard.  Now as I updated the page and took of all the wordpress related links I am unable to again go to the dashboard. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the following url http:// localhost/you-site-path/wp-admin

Answer (score 2):

You can also do http:// localhost/wp-login.php or you can setup your own custom page with form that submits your username and password, then process the login on your own page.

Answer (score 1):

Open yoursite.com/wp-admin and login to view your dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `localhost/your-wp-folder/wp-admin/`

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for,

```
http://localhost/wp-admin/
```

Simply add "wp-admin" after Wordpress site url and you are at the dashboard.

Comment: I think I suggest something wrong.